# Using connect with facebook on a kiosk, will the kiosk IP be banned?

Tags: facebook, kiosk

We are going to run an internet game in a conference on kiosks.

We will be getting signups using Facebook connect on the kiosk. We will be logging out connected users after they play the game.

We are wondering if the IP of the kiosk will get a ban - because multiple users will use connect with facebook feature in a short timespan on the same kiosk.

Can anyone verify if this sort of usage has no problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are expecting a huge flood of signups in very small amount of time, you should be fine. Really, its hard for human action to trigger something like this, its almost always by bots that either do a HUGE amount in a short time, or a small amount consistently over the course of a prolonged time.